# Reverse op for GetKeyNameText

Tags: c, windows, winapi, scancodes

We can use [`GetKeyNameText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeynametexta) to retrieve a string that represents the name of a key. Is there any way to do the reverse, ie get a scancode or virtual key for a given key name?

I want to write key names to a config file so users can edit them easily. When I read in the config file, I would need to do the reverse of `GetKeyNameText()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a good idea, these names are not constant:

> The key name is translated according to the layout of the currently installed keyboard, thus the function may give different results for different input locales.

If you are desperate I suppose you can call `GetKeyNameText` in a loop trying all possible scancodes.

`MapVirtualKey` can convert a scancode to a virtual key if you also need to do that. Virtual keys are stable across all keyboards and all versions of Windows.

I would suggest that you hardcode some of the names that are common and have virtual keys like A-Z, 0-9, Ctrl, Alt, Shift, Home, Insert etc. and store those as English text. Only store the scancode for other strange keys.

Comment: Thanks, yea that seems like the best approach.